# How to create multiple box-shadows in a Stylus function

Tags: css, stylus

I found a SASS function for "starry sci" creating:

```css
// n is number of stars required
@function multiple-box-shadow ($n) 
  $value: '#{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'
  @for $i from 2 through $n
    $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'

  @return unquote($value)

#stars{
    box-shadow: multiple-box-shadow(700)
}
```

I want to translate it to Stylus, but something doesn't work. I try:

```css
random(min, max)
  return floor( math(0, "random") * max + min )

$coordinates = random(1, 2000)px 
$distortion = random(1, 20)px

// n is number of stars required
multiple-box-shadow($n)
  for $i in (1..$n)
    $value = $coordinates  $coordinates $distortion $distortion  #FFFFFF,
    return $value

#stars
    box-shadow multiple-box-shadow(700)
```

random function run only ones and the box-shadow value add only once...
Can anybody help?

Here's a [CodePen snippet](http://codepen.io/Kitana/pen/BNdpqv) to view compiled CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague suggested this solution to me:

```
random(min, max)
  return floor( math(0, "random") * max + min )

// n is number of stars required
multiple-box-shadow($n)
  $coordinates = random(1, 2000)px 
  $distortion = random(1, 20)px
  $value = $coordinates $coordinates $distortion $distortion  #FFFFFF
  for $i in (2..$n)
    $coordinates = random(1, 2000)px 
    $distortion = random(1, 20)px
    $value = $value, $coordinates $coordinates $distortion $distortion  #FFFFFF
  return $value
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
random(min, max)
  return floor(math(0, 'random') * max + min)

multiple-box-shadow($n)
  $value = '%spx %spx #FFF' % (random(1, 2000) random(1, 2000))
  for $i in 2..$n
    $value += ', %spx %spx #FFF' % (random(1, 2000) random(1, 2000))

  return unquote($value)

#stars
  box-shadow: multiple-box-shadow(700)
```